How to use `or` logic in tree-sitter query syntax?
How to use or logic in tree-sitter query?
I want to query out a class's properties and methods:
I tried to use |:
    (class_declaration 
      name: (type_identifier) @class-name
      body: (class_body
        ((public_field_definition 
            name: (property_identifier) @property-name)
        | (method_definition 
            name: (property_identifier) @method-name))))


but this is not work.
and I checked all the query syntax document, didn't find how to implement it.

Use [ ... ], and then no |.
In the docs you referenced, it's called "Alternations".
body: (class_body
  [(public_field_definition 
      name: (property_identifier) @property-name)
   (method_definition 
      name: (property_identifier) @method-name)])

